# SQL - DB2 Group By and indexes with distinct aggregate functions

Tags: sql, group-by, db2, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to flatten out a query result set with some COUNT functions and a GROUP BY clause. Basically, I have a query that can return over a dozen rows for what will essentially be processed as one object. Furthermore, the columns that cause this are only added up after the result set is processed, so this seems an ideal time for aggregation. For example:

```
SELECT 
A.ID, A.NAME, A.DETAILS,
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'ONE' THEN B.ID2 END) AS B1
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'TWO' THEN B.ID2 END) AS B2
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'THREE' 
AND B.SUBTYPE = 'ONE-ONE' THEN B.ID END) AS B3

FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.A_ID = A.ID
GROUP BY A.ID, A.NAME, A.DETAILS
```

The idea is to get a count of all unique associated B objects of various types/subtypes. The problem is that due to the nature of the possible queries and the way the database is structured (This is greatly simplified. There would be numerous joins, subqueries, and some parameters, but this is enough to get the gist), I could possibly get duplicate results for B.ID2 on each instance of A, which necessitates the DISTINCT, otherwise it counts all B.ID2 for that value of A and I get incorrect results. Unfortunately, this causes each aggregate function beyond the first to do a tablescan and create a TEMP table in the explain, and no amount of indexing seems to fix it. I'm not sure I can eliminate the duplicates without some significant changes to the queries that could themselves cause larger performance problems. Without this, I have to join to B on every type/subtype I want, include B.ID2 in the select, and then count them up once the query returns. This is going to seriously bloat the result set and I'd rather avoid it.

Is there a viable alternative here that I'm missing or perhaps some method of indexing those columns that might eliminate the tablescan and TEMP tables? Or is there really no good solution to this?

Comment: Is there a performance target that you are trying to reach, or is it just your aversion to "table scans" and "TEMP tables"? If it's the former, please state the target and the current result, along with the full explain plan as produced by `db2exfmt` and the output of `monreport.dbsummary()` for the duration of the query. Indicating you DB2 version and platform might also be a good idea.

Comment: Seeing relevant starting data/table layout and desired results may help; among other things, use of `DISTINCT` sometimes indicates there may be earlier/cheaper areas to remove duplicates (note that it is occasionally a valid choice, but I tend to become suspicious whenever it's used in an aggregate function).

Comment: Some of these have over half a dozen COUNT() functions in the select and the tablescans and TEMP tables were easily doubling the query cost or more.